# Add imports in OWLAPI

Tags: owl, ontology, owl-api

I'd like to check the consistency of a number of triples by using a reasoner.
There are around 700k triples to check, so for each of them I created a file with the triple and the direct types of its subject and object.

My problem is that if I don't import all the properties everytime I load one of the small file, all ObjectProperty statements are treated as AnnotationAxioms, which doesn't allow to spot any inconsistency.
How can I import all the properties just once and add them to the file with the triples everytime I load one?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**
I add here an example of the small files I am analysing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF
xmlns:wdt="http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/"
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q295376">
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q5"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q21077119">
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q17299750"/>
<wdt:P1346 rdf:resource="http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q295376"/>
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q4993329"/>
</rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

The above lines do not include the import axioms.
Thanks!

Comment: " I import all the properties " -> I guess you mean importing the schema which contains the axioms about the properties used in the triples. Not sure if I got it correctly, but it sounds like you want to check the consistency for each file containing some triples. You have to modify the file before it goes into the parser. One way would be to load the triples as string first and then prepend the schema triples given that you're using N-triples syntax.

Comment: An example of the content of a single file would be helpful. Note, for inconsistency you need particular axioms types like disjointness

Comment: Hi @AKSW thanks for your reply!
I have added an example of these small files above.

Comment: Ok, but what about the schema axioms? I'm wondering which type of axioms your schema contains. In your example, without a disjointness axiom between any of the asserted types and domain/range of the used property, there won't be any inconsistency for sure.

Comment: The schema includes disjointness axioms and the script is able to find inconsistencies if I import the file with all properties everytime I load a small file like that above (I posted a version without the import axiom). My main issue so far is that the script is taking too long to execute for such a large number of files and I would like to find a way of reducing runtime.

Answer (score 0):

It will be much faster to not write the triple to disk. Create tee ontology with declarations for the properties and then add the axiom you wish to test. You can then create the reasoner, test for consistency, discard the reasoner and remove the axiom you just tested. The ontology is then available to be used with another axiom and a new reasoner.

However, you're checking each axiom in isolation; while the axioms might be consistent on their own, this does not provide assurances as to what the axioms will do together - assuming that they will appear in the same ontology after you finish your test.

Comment: Hi @Ignazio thanks for your reply. I was actually trying to do that, but my problem is that I need to add to the ontology an axiom plus the direct types in order to do that.
The files with the axioms and the one with the type axioms are quite big (a couple of Gb), so I had some issues with importing them. I'll try again and will let you know.

Comment: That raises a bigger concern: there are very few reasoners that can work without loading the ontology in memory, and I am not aware of any that interface with the owlapi. The consistency check, under these constraints, might prove unfeasible.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically on how to add an import to an ontology, see the OWLAPI documentation at https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/Add-an-import-directive-to-an-ontology

I don't believe that's the best solution to your scenario, but it's the question you asked :-)

Comment: I tried that, but ObjectProperty axioms weren't recognise by importing the properties file afterwards.

Comment: Everything has to be done **before** parsing the ontology.